# Facebook Ad tracking

Tags: facebook, youtube, instagram, ads

I have posted several Ads to facebook, Instagram which direct users to our website to submit a form. Is there any way to keep the footprint of where member saw the ad and clicked on it so in our CRM we can measure how many users came from facebook or other platform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use UTM parameters at the end of your URLs to tell you how they got to your website.

For example, if you want to track how a specific campaign on FB ads is doing you could use the following:

https://www.example.com/landing-page?utm_campaign=monkey-football&utm_source=facebookads&utm_medium=video-views

The most common UTM parameters are the following:
utm_campaign - Name of the campaign (Optional)
utm_source - Source of the campaign (Facebook, email, Instagram)
utm_medium - Advertising format or medium (e.g. banner, news feed, insta-story)

To have this data captured in your CRM, you need to create fields that will capture this information. Each CRM is different so you'll need to research the best method of doing so. For example, Unbounce, which is not really a CRM platform but a lead generation/landing page platform, can create hidden form fields that will automatically record the UTM parameters in the URL, which then can be transferred to a CRM.

Here is more info from Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732